# Objective-C class unable to respond to helper method

Tags: objective-c

I am receiving the familiar and nonspecific diagnostic: "No visible @interface for... declares the selector ..." I appreciate that this diagnostic has appeared numerous times on this site (I have looked at most of them), but none of the suggested fixes seem to be relevant to my case. Thanks!

I have an old Cocoa program which rotates an OpenGL surface using the mouse. (It is based upon an old Apple demo: NSGL Teapot). The surface is created in an NSOpenGLView (Class SurfaceView) and the code used to perform the rotation is in a helper class called Trackball. When the mouse "slides" on the screen, a method (called rollTo) in a Trackball instance invokes a method (called rotateBy) in SurfaceView which provides the amount of rotation. Unfortunately, Xcode 7.3 complains that NSOpenGLView lacks a visible interface for the rotateBy selector (method).

The code compiled perfectly 15 years ago, but not now. Everything else in the program works fine (i.e., the surface is rendered and it responds correctly to various sliders, etc.) Can you suggest how I can get the OpenGL view to respond to rotateBy?

Thanks very much!

Here is the Interface (indented 4 spaces)

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>
#import <OpenGL/glu.h>
#import <GLUT/glut.h>
#import "Trackball.h"
@interface SurfaceView : NSOpenGLView
{
    float width;
    GLUnurbsObj *theNurb;
    Trackball   *m_trackball;
    // The main rotation
    float   m_rotation[4];
    // The trackball rotation
    float   m_tbRot[4];
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect;
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect;
- (void)rotateBy:(float *)r;
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)zeroRotate;
@end
```

**Method body:**

```
- (void)rotateBy:(float *)r 
 { 
       m_tbRot[0] = r[0];
       m_tbRot[1] = r[1]; 
       m_tbRot[2] = r[2];
       m_tbRot[3]= r[3]; 
}
```

Here is the method in which the error occurs:

```
- (void)rollTo:(NSPoint)pt sender:(NSOpenGLView *)sender
{
    float xxyy;
    float rot[4];
    float cosAng, sinAng;
    float ls, le, lr;

    m_endPt[0] = pt.x - m_ctr.x;
    m_endPt[1] = pt.y - m_ctr.y;
    if (fabs(m_endPt[0] - m_startPt[0]) < kTol && fabs(m_endPt[1] - m_startPt[1]) < kTol)
        return; // Not enough change in the vectors to have an action.

    // Compute the ending vector from the surface of the ball to its center.
    xxyy = m_endPt[0]*m_endPt[0] + m_endPt[1]*m_endPt[1];
    if (xxyy > m_radius*m_radius) {
        // Outside the sphere.
        m_endPt[2] = 0.;
    } else
        m_endPt[2] = sqrt(m_radius*m_radius - xxyy);

    // Take the cross product of the two vectors. r = s X e
    rot[1] =  m_startPt[1] * m_endPt[2] - m_startPt[2] * m_endPt[1];
    rot[2] = -m_startPt[0] * m_endPt[2] + m_startPt[2] * m_endPt[0];
    rot[3] =  m_startPt[0] * m_endPt[1] - m_startPt[1] * m_endPt[0];

    // Use atan for a better angle.  If you use only cos or sin, you only get
    // half the possible angles, and you can end up with rotations that flip around near
    // the poles.

    // cos(a) = (s . e) / (||s|| ||e||)
    cosAng = m_startPt[0]*m_endPt[0] + m_startPt[1]*m_endPt[1] + m_startPt[2]*m_endPt[2]; // (s . e)
    ls = sqrt(m_startPt[0]*m_startPt[0] + m_startPt[1]*m_startPt[1] + m_startPt[2]*m_startPt[2]);
    ls = 1. / ls; // 1 / ||s||
    le = sqrt(m_endPt[0]*m_endPt[0] + m_endPt[1]*m_endPt[1] + m_endPt[2]*m_endPt[2]);
    le = 1. / le; // 1 / ||e||
    cosAng = cosAng * ls * le;

    // sin(a) = ||(s X e)|| / (||s|| ||e||)
    sinAng = lr = sqrt(rot[1]*rot[1] + rot[2]*rot[2] + rot[3]*rot[3]); // ||(s X e)||;
                                // keep this length in lr for normalizing the rotation vector later.
    sinAng = sinAng * ls * le;
    rot[0] = (float)atan2(sinAng, cosAng) * kRad2Deg; // GL rotations are in degrees.

    // Normalize the rotation axis.
    lr = 1. / lr;
    rot[1] *= lr; rot[2] *= lr; rot[3] *= lr;

    [sender rotateBy:rot];
}
```

Comment: Can you share the method definition and interface of the method and class in question?

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new - where do I enter the code?

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO. Just edit your question and add the relevant code. Me or some other community member will take care of formatting if needs be.

Comment: Thanks! I entered the interface for SurfaceView. The method is: - (void)rotateBy:(float *)r
{
    m_tbRot[0] = r[0];
    m_tbRot[1] = r[1];
    m_tbRot[2] = r[2];
    m_tbRot[3] = r[3];
}

Comment: Out of interest, why `float *` and not simply `float`?

Comment: Sorry, not very formatted...

Comment: It is a pointer since r is an array

Comment: That makes sense.  Please show the code calling that method.

Comment: What is the code that is calling `rotateBy:`?  If you are doing something like `[someView rotateBy:value]`, what type is `someView`? It should be a `SurfaceView` and you should have imported `SurfaceView.h`. If `someView` is declared to be an `NSOpenGLView`, or you didn't import the header that contains the declaration of `-rotateBy:`, then the compiler is correct to produce a warning.

Comment: The calling code is in Trackball which is a subclass of NSObject. I tried to make it a SurfaceView but that didn't help

Comment: The calling code is: [sender rotateBy:rot]. This is in rollTo method in Trackball

Comment: Making `Trackball` a `SurfaceView` won't help, because that's not the object you are trying to call `rotateBy:` on! The problem is `sender` is an `NSOpenGLView`, when you want it to be a `SurfaceView` - how are you making the opengl view - _that's_ where you need to make sure that it's a `SurfaceView`. Are you using a xib or creating it in code?

Comment: I am using the original NIB

Comment: The statement "Unfortunately, Xcode 7.3 complains that NSOpenGLView lacks a visible interface for the rotateBy selector (method)" suggests you are not telling Xcode that the class is actually a `SurfaceView` class and not an `NSOpenGLView` class.  Show the code surrounding this warning method.

Comment: The code in which the error occurs is in the original post. The error is: No visible @interface for 'NSOpenGLView' declares the selector 'rotateBy:'

Comment: The error occurs at the end where rotateBy: is invoked. The method rollTo: is in the helper class, Trackball.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `rotateBy:` on `sender` then your method signature needs to have a `sender` that implements that method.

Rewrite it as:

```
- (void)rollTo:(NSPoint)pt sender:(SurfaceView *)sender
```

You could also use a cast on `sender` but that's more dangerous.  (i.e. likely to get a run-time error instead of a compiler one.)

Answer (score 1):

The usage is wrong. It was probably always wrong, only the compiler is now detecting it better.

Your `sender` is declared as `NSOpenGLView` and you are calling `rotateBy:` method on it. `NSOpenGLView` does not have any such method. It's the subclass `SurfaceView` that has the method.

One simple fix is to declare `sender` as `id`, to completely remove type information.

A better fix is to declare the `sender` parameter correctly as `SurfaceView`.

If you need to keep the same interface, just perform a cast

```
[(SurfaceView *) sender rotateBy:rot];
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks, the cast worked perfectly. Many thanks!!

Comment: Many thanks to Sulthan and Phillip Mills (and others) for their very helpful answers to my Cocoa query. It illustrates very nicely the superb utility of this site!